# Use name of object to run a function

Tags: javascript

I would like to do the following in JavaScript:

```
var myObject.name = myString;

function newFunction(){myObject.name}
```

Is it possible to use a string as the contents of a function?  How would you convert it to be usable?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you're trying to do. Functions are supposed to *do* something whereas strings and other basic types are supposed to *be* something. Why would you want to make a function which contains only a string?

Comment: Your intent is unclear here.  The code you've posted is valid, but doesn't "do" anything. You could `return myObject.name` to get the string back out of the function, but unless that's what you're after, we need to know more about what your goal is.

Comment: I think he wants the string to be the function's body. Like `myString = "return x;"` -in which case he could use `eval()`

Comment: would you like to treat the contents of the string `myObject.name` as javascript and execute it? if so you could use [eval](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/ecmascript/quickref/eval.html)

Comment: or similarly:  `var myObject.name = "x=1,y=1" "function(){myObject.name; var myArray = []; myArray = myObject.name; return myArray}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want `myString` to hold *code*, right ?

You can execute that code by using the [`eval()`<sup>MDN docs</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) method.

```
function newFunction(){ eval(myObject.name); }
```

---

***Warning !***

be sure to read the [***Don't use eval!***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Don%27t_use_eval!) section though ..

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I get what you're trying to do. You can do it like this:

```
var newFunction = new Function(myObject.name);
```

This means if `myObject.name` equals `"alert('it works')"`, when you call `newFunction()` you will be alerted. (`new Function(code)` is an alternative to `eval`, specifically for what you're doing.)

But this is considered very bad practice in JavaScript (and in programming in general), as code that can alter itself can quickly become unmanageable, and there's usually a better way to do things. Unless you show us what it is you're doing, I can't say what that better way is.

Comment: I like this approach better than the solutions using `eval()`.  It's a bit cleaner syntactically.  +1.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `eval()` to do this, assuming `myObject.name` contains valid Javascript:

```
function newFunction(){ eval( myObject.name ); };
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript has [the `eval()` function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eval#JavaScript) but that's generally not a function you want to be using...

You'd then write:

```
var myObject.name = myString;

function newFunction() {
    eval(myObject.name);
}
```

However, this is generally a dangerous and bad idea - on a higher level, what are you trying to do?